# How can I select files in Midnight Commander on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I find really annoying to use Midnight Commander under OS X when using the non-extended keyboard (laptop).

I found no way of simulating an INSERT key press (select file) and I would like to find a solution that does not require me to reconfigure MC, specially because I cannot do this with each machine I'm connecting to from my MacBook.

I will give extra bonus ;) for and extended solution what will solve the problem not only for the INSERT (select file) but also for switch selection and add/substract selection (NumMultiply,NumMinus,NumPlus).

Remember that Numlock area *, + and - are not the same as the ones from the standard keyboard.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is standard hotkey for file selection — http://linux.die.net/man/1/mc.

As for switch/add/substract, just type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> for *, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> for + and <kbd>-</kbd> for minus.

All this works in MC out of the box.

Comment: ^T works but the others do not and I tried to use an external keyboard and when I press *, + or - from the keypad it will work.

Comment: That's strange. Works for me though (with iTerm2). What happens then? Make sure your command line is clear when you do that.

Comment: Interesting, I am also using iTerm2 and pressing the keypad *-+ it doesn't bring the selection window.

Comment: That's all I can help you with, unfortunately.

Comment: I have problem to prevent Unselect dialog when pressing minus, did anyone solve this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337008/how-to-avoid-unselect-file-dialog-when-pressing-minus-sign-in-midnight-commander ?

Answer (score 13):

Control+T will select files:

http://austringer.net/wp/index.php/2008/06/07/mac-os-x-and-midnight-commander-the-missing-insert-key/

Answer (score 4):

Holding <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> while pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>  will also select the file.

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> is easier for me to reach and skip over files I don't want to select compared to <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @SergeyKirienko  I guess you're using the native OSX Terminal app? There's something about the native Terminal app that doesn't send Shift + Arrow keystrokes correctly (probably you need to fiddle with some settings in Terminal or in OSX System Preferences).   You might want to try iTerm[link](https://iterm2.com/) . iTerm works out of the box with Shift + Arrow. I've tried the above Shift + Arrow and it works locally (with homebrew version of mc) and also through SSH/mosh/tmux.

Answer (score 3):

For those like me who were drawn here by a Google search based on the title of the question (not relating to Midnight Commander), I still haven't found a great solution.  However, for Word processors (a common usage of needing to find the "insert" key to toggle Insert/Overwrite mode), you should be able to click the text that says "INSRT" or "OVER"/"OVWT" in the status bar on the bottom of the Word Processor to change modes, as detailed [here for Open Office](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/office_guides/openoffice_writer_user_guide/openoffice_guide_Switching_between_insert_and_overwrite_mode.html).  Not awesome, but at least functional.

If neither Midnight Commander nor a Word Processor drew you here, then...good luck in your quest!

Answer (score 3):

As @slackair has suggested to use a convenient combination

> Holding shift ⇧ while pressing ↑ or ↓ will also select the file.

However, this does not work out of the box in Mac Terminal, but you can setup a key to action mapping in your profile keyboard settings as following:

```
Shift ⇧ + ↑ to \033[1;2A
Shift ⇧ + ↓ to \033[1;2B
```

[image: Screenshot of Profiles dialog]

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to select **all files**: first press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> - Midnight Commander will prompt for a selection options (* by default), then just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> - works fine in Terminal.app

Answer (score 0):

I use iTerm2. IMHO Midnight Commander with iTerm2 works better.
https://iterm2.com/

```
brew install iterm2
```