# How to avoid unselect file dialog when pressing minus sign in Midnight commander on macOS

Tags: keyboard, iterm

When I try to type a minus character (e.g. `open -a TextEdit`) in the MC subshell, instead of minus the `Unselect` dialog pops up.

[image: Trying to type - into the command line]

I'm using iTerm2 and Midnight commander via Homebrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit `~/.config/mc/ini` config file and look for `only_leading_plus_minus` entry. By default it is set to `false` which causes this behavior. If you set it to `true`

```
only_leading_plus_minus=true
```

then `-` will trigger `Unselect` dialog only if `-` is the first character you type which pretty much would never be a problem. If you do not have `only_leading_plus_minus` just add it. Make sure you do not have `Auto save setup` enabled in your config and if you do, quit all instances of `mc` prior editing your `ini`.

Comment: I have been waiting ages for this. Many thanks. How did you discover this?

Comment: Ha, i knew that despite question being bit old there is a chance you still struggling with that :) I was desperate to get this disabled (as it's annoying AF) and even to dig in the source codes but luckily decided to check the man page for mc first and found "special setting" section - worth checking. Here's online version https://linux.die.net/man/1/mc